# How to update a boolean variable in the function which is passing as a parameter

Tags: c, boolean

In the mentioned code, how to get the updated value in the statement of `printf("value : %d\n",a);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TRUE 1;
#define FALSE 0;

void printbool(bool a);
int main()
{
    bool a = FALSE;
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printbool(a);
    printf("value : %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}

void printbool(bool a)
{
    a = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Don’t put semicolons at the end of `#define` lines.

Comment: If you use stdbool.h you should not invent ugly macros like TRUE/FALSE but instead use standard C `true`/`false`.

Comment: Also, the function name `printbool()` is a major misnomer; it does no printing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just addressed that in my answer , sir. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
void printbool(bool *a)
{
  *a = TRUE;
}
```

In main, call function like this: `printbool(&a);`

Answer (score 4):

C uses pass-by value for function argument passing, thereby changes made to a received parameter inside the function will not reflect to the caller.

You can either

- return the new value and store into the original variable

  ```
  bool changebool(bool a)
  {
      a = TRUE;
      return a;
  }
  ```

  and, in `main()`

  ```
  a = changebool(a);
  ```
- pass a pointer to the original variable and make change to the value at the address pointer is pointing to.

  ```
  void changebool(bool* a)
  {
      *a = TRUE;
  }
  ```

  and, in `main()`

  ```
  changebool(&a);
  ```

Note:

1. Get rid of the `;`s in the `#define`, they are not needed and likely to cause problems later on.
2. [`stdbool.h` already defines `true` and `false`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/stdbool.h.html), you can make use of them instead trying to define your own constants.
3. In approach 1, we need to change the return type of the function.
4. Please use a meaningful name to functions, not to confuse the future readers (including yourself). I already did to my example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a pointer and then dereference inside the function in order to change/alter the passed argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void printbool(bool *a);
int main()
{
    bool a = FALSE;
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printbool(&a);
    printf("value : %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}

void printbool(bool *a)
{
    *a = TRUE;
}
```

Also notice that you don't need to `define TRUE` and `FALSE` if you are including `stdbool.h`, instead use `true` and `false`.

Comment: or, we can just return the new value. :)

Comment: Yes sir, you're right, but based on the title it seems that OP wants to alter the passed parameter: _which is passing as a parameter_

Comment: Never said you are wrong sir (heck, I also wrote what you wrote), just saying.... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void printbool(bool a)
```

needs to be

```
void printbool(bool *a)
```

and assign through the pointer:

```
*a=TRUE;
```

call as

```
printbool(&a);
```

Basic stuff - you need to know this.